# i wanted to detect objects in a hsv image. but i keep getting an error,,Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: opencv

i was trying to create a trackbar window and get hsv value of the image by adjusting the trackbar. created a mask and then adjusted the trackbar to detect an object of the hsv image

enter code here

```
   def nothing(x):
      pass

cv.namedWindow("Tracking")
cv.createTrackbar("LH","Tracking",0,255,nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("LS","Tracking",0,255,nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("LV","Tracking",0,255,nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("UH","Tracking",255,255,nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("US","Tracking",255,255,nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("UV","Tracking",255,255,nothing)
while True:
    frame = cv.imread("C:/Users/acer/Desktop/insects/New folder/ins.jpg")
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    l_h = cv.getTrackbarPos("LH","Tracking")
    l_s = cv.getTrackbarPos("LS","Tracking")
    l_v = cv.getTrackbarPos("LV","Tracking")

    u_h = cv.getTrackbarPos("UH","Tracking")
    u_s = cv.getTrackbarPos("US","Tracking")
    u_v = cv.getTrackbarPos("UV","Tracking")

    l_b = np.array([l_h,l_s,l_v])
    u_b = np.array([u_h,u_s,u_v])

    mask = (hsv,l_b,u_b)

    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

    cv.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv.imshow("res",res)

    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I got the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1) You have no `import` statements. You need at least:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
```

2) Your indentation is incorrect. Your function `nothing()` should not be indented.

3) You omitted to call `inRange()`, you need:

```
mask = cv.inRange(hsv,l_b,u_b)
```

4) You have scaled the Hue into the range 0..255 when it actually has the range 0..180 when used with `uint8` images so that 360 degrees comes out as 180 degrees which is less than the 255 upper limit of `uint8`.

By the way, it is fairly poor practice to do *"loop invariant"* stuff inside a loop - I mean the part where you hit the disk every millisecond and re-read the image, re-decode the JPEG and convert it to HSV. All that can be done outside the loop, then inside it, just do a quick memory copy of the HSV image.

Comment: Actually, while posting the question the import statement got erased by mistake adn the indentation got wrong....

Comment: and thanks for your 3rd and 4th comment. its a very useful insight...my issue was resolved.. and also thanx for the great tip about "loop invariant" stuff..